# Narrow a pool which has already lanes in a BPMN diagram

Tags: enterprise-architect, bpmn

There is an existing BPMN diagram which has a pool. Within the Pool there are three Lanes. Currently, I can expand the Pool to add additional elements into the diagram.

However, I cannot narrow down the Pool (i.e. decrease the pool in length). In order to do so, I have to either delete the pool and narrow the Lanes, or delete the Lanes and narrow the pool.

Is there a way to narrow the Pool and the Lanes still be there?

I am using EA 16.

Thanks,

Comment: Swimlanes?? You realy use these together with pools in BPMN? Or do you mean Lanes?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean Pool and Lane from BPMN: The Pool can not be smaller than the largest Lane or respectively the one stretching out most to the right(/bottom) inside.

**Manual steps**

Start scenario. Pool contains 2 Lanes and is minimized.
[image]

Top right Lane is selected by clicking into it and narrowed down a bit.
[image]

Pool is selected by clickin into it (or if space is occupied by Lanes into the name field). It can then be narrowed to to the extent of the Lane top right.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the info. However, neither the lanes can be narrowed down. They can only be extended.

Comment: Please fix your question since swimlanes are only some graphical gimmicks and no Lanes at all. Re. your comment: select any Lane and narrow it to your needs. Move them if needed. Finally you can narrow the Pool.